# Is there a Rails 4 backports library?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, backport

Over time, we're upgrading pieces of our Rails 3.2.x application to be Rails 4 compatible.  For example, any of our new code is written using strong parameters instead of `attr_accessible`.  We'd like to take a similar approach for features like ActiveRecord's `none` and `find_or_create_by` so we don't have to change much code when we finish our upgrade to Rails 4.

Is there a Rails 4 backports library that can assist us with this?  We currently have a collection of monkey patches, but it seems like there would be a gem for this.

Comment: Retrospective comment: we decided to just focus on upgrading our app (which always takes good amount of time).  But backports could have been helpful in making that process easier.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. As you noticed, certain features are provided as a gem (such as `strong_params`) that you can easily install in your previous version.

In case of some serious deprecations, the Rails core team normally includes a deprecation message in the old version along with a backport, so that you can fix the deprecation before upgrading the release.

In the case of `none`, this is not a deprecation but a feature. Unless you find this in a gem, you are forced to upgrade to Rails 4 in order to use it.

`find_or_create_by` is a deprecation, but Rails 4.0 still supports it. Thus you can upgrade and remove the code later.

Generally speaking, a backport with deprecation is normally provided only for those changes that will cause an incompatibility immediately after the upgrade preventing your application to even start or run properly.